# Find the reason why windows 7 froze

Tags: windows-7, freeze, compaq-laptop

I'm the new 'It guy' at my company for about 6 weeks now. In the office from a previous IT'er did I find a HP Compaq 8710p Laptop. This laptop is physically labeled `Old PC PersonsName, Froze after weekend 02/05/2017`. That's about 9 months ago.

I've booted the pc and it works fine for now.
I've ran a `chkdsk`and found nothing.
Running `sfc /scannow`didn't give anything.
MemTest86+ couldn't seem to find anything either.

Is there a way that I could find any logs or something why the computer suddenly froze? Also how could I try to trigger the freeze and start troubleshooting?

Comment: Install WhoCrashed and check for crash dump files. If you want to bench test it, you could run Prime95 on it for a few hours, and/or run Memtest

Comment: there are no set answers to your questions. a booted computer is a system that is precariously balanced house of cards, desperately trying to hold itself together. it requires so many things to be working together at all times, that any other state is catastrophic. there are far more things that could make it fail than there are that could make it succeed. Anyway, freezes are hard to diagnose because the system can't log anything about the event (it has already turned into a vegetable). start by testing the OS integrity on disk, the health of the disk, and the health of the RAM.

Comment: I've edited the question with the tests done.